# Detecting if a user is online in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Is there a built-in way to find out whether or not a user has logged in?

Basically I would want to know if a user has logged in.

I mean, I could keep track of the users that are logging via overriding methods in authentication and storing session info.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to do this. If you want to develop a solution for this, then you need to clarify which authentication methods you are looking for: Windows, Forms, Claims ?

See this thread:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6830/how-to-check-how-many-users-are-currently-logged-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010

Comment: Windows Forms and Claims. (all)